# php7:error pid 12451 PHP Fatal error: require(): Failed opening required

Tags: php, laravel, apache, ubuntu

```
[php7:error] [pid 12451] [client 90.165.75.239:54526] PHP Fatal error:  require(): Failed opening required '/var/www/midser/vendor/composer/../codedge/laravel-selfupdater/src/helpers.php' (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/midser/vendor/composer/autoload_real.php on line 66
```

Getting this error whenever I'm trying to get my site up and running. Which is causing the browser to give me this error:

```
HTTP ERROR 500
```

Does anybody know why may cause this error? Thank you very much! Any help I would appreciate it. The server is running on Laravel and ubuntu with apache.

Comment: Well, the error message is crystal clear, isn't it? If you think not, then please tell us why...

Comment: I think there are some errors with composer and a package. Isn't it that?

Comment: That is what the error message says, indeed. It even tells you exactly _what_ the issue is and where in the code it occurs.

Answer (score 0):

Try to update your dependencies using composer by running

```
composer update
```

Then run :

```
composer dump-autoload
```

The issue is caused by the package : [codedge/laravel-selfupdater](https://github.com/codedge/laravel-selfupdater)

either you remove it and re-install it, or you update it using composer ( the solution above), and I recommend to remove it and reinstall it